# Instanciação de objetos em php

Tags: php

Estou com algumas dificuldades na instanciação de objetos em php.

Eu tenho o código em OO:

```
class Usuario {  

    private $idade;  
    private $nome;  

    public function getNome() {  
        return $this->nome;  
    }  

    public function setNome($nome) {  
        $this->nome=$nome;  
    }  

    public function getIdade() {  
        return $this->idade;  
    }  

    public function setIdade($idade) {  
        $this->idade=$idade;  
    }  

}
```

E a classe de teste:

```
include("Usuario.php");  

classe TesteUsuario {  

    $usuario1 = TesteUsuario();  
    $usuario2 = New Usuario();  
 }
```

Instanciando o objeto dentro do escopo da classe, dá o erro:

> ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'TesteUsuario' (T_STRING) in C:\wamp\www\listas\TesteUsuario.php on line 4 >

Se instanciar fora também dá erro.

Como faço? Já percebi que eu posso usar o arquivo de teste sem classe, ou seja:

```
 include("Usuario.php");  

 $usuario2 = New Usuario();
```

Comment: É pouco provável que queria fazer isso de fato. Fazendo fora funciona perfeita se usar a sintaxe correta. Tem vários erros nesse código. Fazendo dentro da classe é o que já foi respondido, mas para criar uma instância da própria classe no construtor dela não dá.

Comment: @bigown♦ quais são os erros de do código? Grato.

Answer (score 4):

No php não é possível armazenar instâncias diretamente na declaração das propriedades, como se faz em `C#`.

Você pode resolver o problema fazendo isso no construtor.

```
class TesteUsuario {

     protected $usuario;

     public function __construct() {
         $this->usuario = new Usuario;
     }
}
```

Outra coisa que reparei é que você não declarou a visibilidade das propriedades. No PHP é necessário definir `public`, `protected` ou `private` para as propriedades. Em versões mais antigas podia-se definir `var`, mas esse recurso é desencorajado a partir da versão 5 do php.

Veja:

```
classe TesteUsuario {  

    $usuario1 = TesteUsuario();  
    $usuario2 = New Usuario();  
 }
```

A forma correta seria:

```
classe TesteUsuario {  

    public $usuario1;
    protected $usuario2;
 }
```

Referências:

- [Visibilidade](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.visibility.php)
- [Propriedades](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.properties.php)
- [Construtores e Destrutores](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.decon.php)

Comment: não percebo  falta de visibilidade.

Answer (score 4):

Não é possível atribuir objetos criados diretamente a uma propriedade ou chmadas de funções. No php isso deve ser feito no construtor. Apenas valores fixos e alguns tipos de expressões são permitidos.

No lugar de:

```
classe TesteUsuario {  

    $usuario1 = TesteUsuario();  
    $usuario2 = New Usuario();  
 }
```

Modifique para:

```
classe TesteUsuario {  
  private $usuario1;
  private $usuario2;

  public function __construct(){
    $this->usuario1 = TesteUsuario();  
    $this->usuario2 = New Usuario();  
  }
}
```

Comment: dessa vez quem foi mais rápido?

Comment: @rray E mesmo não atribuindo dados a uma propriedade ou atributo, como devo fazer a instanciação, já que não permite dentro do escopo da classe?

Comment: @AndréNascimento conseguiu resolver? está faltando alguma coisa?

Comment: @rray♦ eu consegui fazer sem a segunda classe. Só mantive a classe Usuario e a classe TesteUsuario eu excluí. Quando eu instancio o Usuario no arquivo que seria a classe TesteUsuario funciona. Mas não consigo fazer a erança e instanciar o objeto como down cast. Já percebi que tem alguma diferença em relação ao java.

Comment: Para quem está com dúvida no que eu quero fazer, não é nada de mais. Só estou estudando php mesmo.

Comment: @AndréNascimento blz então eu não demorei p olhar a pergunta, ai achei tinha algo pendente.

Answer (score 0):

Entendi o que você deseja fazer, porém, não compreendi o motivo ou necessidade. Veja se seria isso:

```
<?php
class Usuario {  

    private $idade;  
    private $nome;  

    public function getNome() {  
        return $this->nome;  
    }  

    public function setNome($nome) {  
        $this->nome=$nome;  
    }  

    public function getIdade() {  
        return $this->idade;  
    }  

    public function setIdade($idade) {  
        $this->idade=$idade;  
    }  

}
```

Aqui o que estava "errado":

```
<?php
include("usuario.php");  

class TesteUsuario {  

    private $usuario1;
    private $usuario2;

    function __construct($instancia = null)
    {
        $this->usuario1 = $instancia;
        var_dump($this->usuario1);
        $this->usuario2 = new Usuario; 
    }
 }

 new TesteUsuario(new TesteUsuario);
```

Em PHP você não vai conseguir atribuir um objeto criado na definição dos atributos, vai precisar de um construtor para isso.

***Passei a solução acima, porém, no meu entendimento esse uso não está "correto", ou ao menos não representa uma utilização dentro do entendimento comum.***