# Erro ao chamar a função rand() na definição de uma propriedade

Tags: php

Tenho um código de "Esqueci Senha". E na hora de gerar o número aleatório para enviar pro email, está me dando este erro:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' on
>   line 9

[image: Imagem do erro]

alguem pode me ajudar quanto a isso?

```
//Criar um código aleátorio
var $min    = 000001;
var $max    = 100000;
var $codigo = rand($min,$max);
//fim criar código aleátorio
```

Comment: Poste a linha do erro e anterior.

Comment: dei um up no post!

Comment: Bem ... desconfio isso seja definição classe, no php vc não atribuir um valor dessa maneira teria que fazer isso no construtor. obs: `var` era usado no php4 ou seja se o código não é legado não use isso, troque por um dos modificadores de acesso.

Comment: @rray sim tem uma classe só pelo o motivo de que preciso acessar a **var $codigo** novamente! fora isso nao precisaria!

Comment: Explicando o que o @rray disse, você não pode chamar funções (como `rand`) na definição das propriedades da classe, somente no construtor.

Comment: @bfavaretto ah sim agora ficou claro, mas como poderia acessar esse `rand` em outro construtor ?

Comment: Acho que [essa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/153924/91) resolve ou ajuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não pode chamar funções (como `rand`) na definição das propriedades da classe, somente no construtor. O construtor é uma função especial executada sempre que uma instância da classe é criada, e no PHP tem o nome `__construct`. Por exemplo:

```
class MinhaClasse {

    private $min = 1;
    private $max = 10;
    private $valor;

    function __construct() {
        $this->valor = rand($this->min, $this->max);
    }
}
```

Comment: Isto resolve porem me apareceu este erro! **`Fatal error: Call to undefined function enviacodigo() | echo enviacodigo($email);`**

Comment: Aí parece outro problema, talvez seja o caso de postar outra pergunta. Em `echo enviacodigo($email)`, você não pode chamar a função assim, porque ela é um método da classe, não uma função global. De dentro da classe, você deve chamá-la com `$this->enviacodigo($email)`.

Answer (score -1):

No PHP a função de gerar números randomicos é a seguinte:

```
mt_rand(inicio, fim)
```

Então, testa com o seu código assim:

```
//Criar um código aleátorio
var $min    = 000001;
var $max    = 100000;
var $codigo = mt_rand($min,$max);
//fim criar código aleátorio
```

A função `mt_rand()` gera um número inteiro usando o algorítmo "Mersenne Twister".
Além disso, ele é 4 vezes mais rápido do que o `rand()` que você estava tentando usar.

Fonte: Site do W3 Schools.

Comment: Você não pode atribuir uma propriedade da classe com determinadas expressões ou outra variável.

Comment: @Dante continua o erro **Dante**. @@rray não consegui entender a resposta que me mandaste

Comment: Mas ele poderia informar diretamente os valores no mt_rand() e utilizar em outro lugar. (Chamar direto no construtor e passar ao invés de colocar no código dele)

Comment: Lucas, esse número random você pode gerar toda vez que executar o construtor de sua página e usar esse valor armazenado. Ou então, passar essa responsabilidade para o seu Controller(O que seria muito melhor)