# Tem como usar uma função na declaração de um atributo no PHP?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, classes

Olá.

É possível fazer algo do tipo:

```
class Net
{
 public static $ip = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");
}
```

Pegar o retorno de uma função e atribuir diretamente na propriedade?

Ou então criar uma variável fora da classe e atribui-la à uma propriedade (sem usar métodos para isso):

```
$ipUser = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");

class Net
{
public static $ip = $ipUser;
}
```

é porque trata-se de uma classe que só possui propriedades, e estas propriedades estão sendo acessadas no contexto estático, então não posso usar um construtor ou algo do tipo... ou posso?

Comment: `Net::ip = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");` tem algum problema em usar ou não atende o seu requisito? [relacionada](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/153923/91)

Comment: Neste caso foi só um exemplo. :x minha situação real é uma classe configurações que possui um atributo 'approot', que eu queria que recebesse um caminho diferente dependendo do ambiente (local ou web), se o ip for 127.0.0.1 recebe caminho x, se for outro, caminho y. ai eu criaria uma função pra verificar o ip.

Comment: se não tiver jeito, vou criar um método pra isso. Mas queria saber se tem como, pra fins de experiência.

Comment: Parece que é duplicada: [Instanciação de objetos em PHP](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/153923/instancia%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-objetos-em-php?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não, não tem como.

O PHP não permite definir valores dinâmicos em atributos de classes de maneira literal.

Você precisa utilizar o construtor para isso:

```
class Net
{
    public $ip;

    public function __construct() {
       $this->ip = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");
    }
}

$net = new Net;

echo $net->ip;
```

Ou, se for usar estaticamente, é necessário criar algum método para inicializar os atributos:

```
class Net
{
    public static $ip;

    public static function init() {
       static::$ip = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");
    }
}


Net::init();

echo Net::$ip;
```